# How do I get spring-ws + tomcat to log errors

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-ws

I'm creating a Spring-WS based webservice and running it in tomcat. I  made some change and now get a fault with OperationUnsupportedException.

I'd like to see the entire stack trace that Spring-WS is getting, but cannot figure out how to have it logged.

Does anybody know how to have this stack trace logged somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a log4j.properties file to the root of your source folder with the following settings:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.logger.package.name.that.you.are.interested.in=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR
```

Then the stacktrace should be printed in the terminal window you started the application from.

**Updated**

That's good you found a solution with log4j.

But if you're relatively new to log4j, I will recommend you to take a look at [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/) framework. I have written about how to route log messages from Apache Commons Logging and log4J to SLF4J [here](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/06/06/slf4j-logging-with-log4j-and-jcl/). (Tomcat and Spring logs with Apache Commons Logging)

Comment: Thanks.  I had to enable log4j, but this got me started and I found more docs at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html